# Android Emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg Error

Tags: avd-manager, intel-haxm

- **Machine**: HP ZBook 15 G3
- **Processor**:   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz, 2712 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
- **System**: Windows 10.0.16299 Build 16299
- **Android**: Studio: Android Studio 3.1.4
- **Haxm version**: 7.3.0
- **Hardware Virtualization enabled in Bios**: Yes

Brand new install of Android Studio.

I cannot run any X86/X86_64 Android emulators. They terminate as soon as I start them with the error "Failed to sync vcpu reg". I have restarted several times and use no other virtualisation tools, although I believe the latest Haxm has solved that issue, so previous answers all suggest this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should add that Hyper-V is not enabled in Windows

Comment: I have some suggestions, but please confirm if you have tried **[these workarounds suggested from StackOverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17024538/7551330)**?

Comment: I can confirm that I tried all of the suggested comments. Most of them are to do with multiple VM's which is no longer relevant

Answer (score 1):

Do you have HP SureClick running? I had the same problem on the Zbook Studio x360 G5 until I disabled it.